# Beaglebone Black GPIO control running stepper motor very slowly. How can I improve speed?

Tags: c, module, beagleboneblack, gpio, stepper

I have written a device driver for the Beaglebone Black that simply rotates my 28BJY-48 stepper motor connected through a ULN2003A board. Everything works fine, the motor rotates, however I have found necessary to use `msleep(1)` after each pin is switched to HIGH for the motor to "capture" the signal. If I let the loop run without any sleep time nothing happens with the motor.

What I am trying to do is speed up the motor rotation.

My logic is that the signal is too fast for the motor to respond. I know the signal is being sent because the LEDs in series with the motor coils light up.

I have read the data sheet and instructions provided by Elegoo [found here for referene](http://eeshop.unl.edu/pdf/Stepper+Driver.pdf).

For ease of understanding, I have attached the wiring diagram:
[image: Driver diagram]

I have assigned the following GPIOs of P8 as controls:

```
GPIO11 - IN1 - BLUE wire (coil 4)
GPIO12 - IN2 - PINK wire (coil 3)
GPIO15 - IN3 - YELLOW wire (coil 2)
GPIO16 - IN4 - ORANGE wire (coil 1)
```

The way I have am controlling the GPIOs is by using `ioremap()`.

Here is the part of the code that controls the motor:

```
static ssize_t motor_rotate(int i) { //0 rotates right, 1 rotates left
    int c = 0;

    motor_stop();

    while(c < 2000) 
    {   
        *gpio_dataout_addr |= PIN11;
        //msleep(1);
        *gpio_dataout_addr &= (0xFFFFFFFF ^ PIN16);
        *gpio_dataout_addr |= PIN12;
        //msleep(1);
        *gpio_dataout_addr &= (0xFFFFFFFF ^ PIN11);
        *gpio_dataout_addr |= PIN15;
        //msleep(1);
        *gpio_dataout_addr &= (0xFFFFFFFF ^ PIN12);
        *gpio_dataout_addr |= PIN16;
        //msleep(1);
        *gpio_dataout_addr &= (0xFFFFFFFF ^ PIN15);

        c++;
    }

    motor_stop();

    return 0;   
}

static ssize_t motor_stop(void){
    *gpio_dataout_addr &= (0xFFFFFFFF ^ (PIN11 | PIN12 | PIN15 | PIN16));

    return 0;
}
```

I have my motor hooked to a 5v power supply independent of the Beaglebone. Any help or pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

On a side note, is there a way to simultaneously set 2 pins to LOW and 2 to HIGH? My code sets one pin low before setting another high. I would like to know if I could do both in one step. I can't seem to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further review and research I found that the problem lies not with voltage, motor, or board, but with my code itself.

[As per this link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt) I found that msleep has a minimum limitation of about 20ms. Anything below 20ms (in my case, 1ms) will be run at 20ms. Therefore the proper function to achieve <20ms delays would be one of the following:

`usleep_range()`, using a range of 1000-2000, has yielded me a good result with faster rotation. While holding the motor, however, I feel that it skips a couple of steps, although invisible to the eye. I believe this to be either a voltage fault or a motor limitation. Further analysis would be required to rule out what causes the skipping.

I am still playing with this range to figure out what is the optimal non-skip range range.

`udelay()` also works, however the system seems to freeze in some permanent loop and a hard reboot is required. Further analysis is required to figure out what exactly is causing the system to hang after completion of rotation loop.

Comment: Note that due to the beagle bone having an operating system there is significant context switching from the driver code to the operating system, hence the skipping steps mentioned in the answer. Because of this it is recommended to control the motor using a controller that does not run an OS, such as an Arduino. The Arduino can then be interfaced with the beagle bone if necessary.